# Add-in auth in outlook and SSO

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am a new developer working on an Outlook add-in where I need to extract attachments and email info and store them into a OneDrive, but I don't know how to go around it. I'm using React with Typescript.
I wanted to get the access token from the logged in user and use that token to access GraphAPI. from that thought I tried using Office.auth.getAccessToken(), according to Microsoft docs "Calls the Azure Active Directory V 2.0 endpoint to get an access token to your add-in's web application. Enables add-ins to identify users" but when I side load the Add-in in Outlook I get 13000 error "Not supported" I am on windows 11 and using Outlook app.

The entire point is to not have the users sign in again in the add-in.

Edit: I found out you can create a template that implements SSO by default however the add-in keeps asking the users to login every time the "get user information" button is pressed that is the default button. When I created the add-in I used the admin account when running npm run configure-sso, and I checked the app created for granting admin consent. but for no use...

Comment: Do the samples at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/ work for you?

Comment: Thanks for sharing samples. Also, for attachments specifically here is a documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item 
General outlook addin apis doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-1.13
Docs for SSO- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token
Creating a sample addin- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview

Comment: thank you the attachment docs were very helpful, however the idea is to upload these into SharePoint sites that the user has access to, when I tried getting the access token using getAccessToken() I got an error that it's not supported, I looked into it and I found out that this hook isn't supported on the web, but i was using the new outlook on windows 11. is it because the new one is built as a webapp? if yes how can I go around it?

Comment: Can you share more details of exact hook you are trying to use? Probably a snippet if possible. 
The getAccessToken api should work and using the token for graph api access should work as well. 
Also, behavior of new outlook would be same as web.

Comment: I'd suggest being more specific with issues you faced with. If you have problems with the `getAccessToken` method then I'd recommend describing in details what exactly you did to get SSO configured on your side. Your description `I am using Application authentication and I have granted the proper permissions.` is not enough to get any valuable help.

Comment: I edited the post I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @MarwanSummakieh Please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph#how-it-works-at-runtime to understand how SSO works. The token returned by getAccessToken does not provide access to Microsoft Graph. It provides access to the add-in's own server-side APIs. The server-side code uses the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) to request a new access token with permissions to Microsoft Graph.
Are you following these steps?

Answer (score 0):

To work with SSO you need to register your add-in with the Microsoft identity platform. This will enable the Microsoft identity platform to provide authentication and authorization services for your add-in. Creating the app registration includes the following tasks.

- Get an application (client) ID to identify your add-in to the Microsoft identity platform.
- Generate a client secret to act as a password for your add-in when requesting a token.
- Specify the permissions that your add-in requires. The Microsoft Graph `profile` and `openid` permissions are always required. You may need additional permissions depending on what your add-in needs to do.
- Grant the Office applications trust to the add-in.
  Pre-authorize the Office applications to the add-in with the default scope access_as_user.

Make sure that you did all of that before running the code.

For more details about this process, see [Register an Office Add-in that uses SSO with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2).