no support for OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken in Outlook add-ins but in Excel yes?
The Short Summary: Why does Office.auth.getAccessToken or OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken works on Excel but not on Outlook. And why even though my Outlook version support the Idenitity API it show the message he identity API is not supported for this add-in.","code":13000
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=common-js-preview
if I hardcode the const apiToken and const graphToken(see the commit above) it seems to work well so the problem lies in the getAccessToken function. Why does it work in excel but not in outlook?
Longer context:
I forked this repo and tried to transform it to an outlook addin: msgraph-sample-office-addin - github
I am working on an Outlook add-in and encountered an issue with the OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken method. The error message I received is:
getAccessToken error: {"name":"API Not Supported","message":"The identity API is not supported for this add-in.","code":13000}

Even though the same code, the same API to allow the permissions does work as an Excel addin.
Additionally, the backend error indicates that the token being sent to the server is undefined or invalid:
Verify error: {"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"jwt must be provided"}

I have made some changes to the manifest and taskpane.js to make it work in Outlook instead of Excel. However, I am still facing the issue.
Here are the relevant code snippets:
Manifest changes(please scroll down to manifest.xml:
commit of the changes
taskpane.js changes:
commit of the changes
if I hardcode the const apiToken and const graphToken (see the commit above), it seems to work well, so the problem lies in the getAccessToken function. Why does it work in Excel but not in outlook?
Similar question but another error message: OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken working in Excel but not in Outlook

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265402/add-in-auth-in-outlook-and-sso

thank you, I did all that multiple times and there is still the same error, and as I have written, when hardcoding both tokens directly into the code (I do that by running the same addin on excel without the changes but with the same app registration) and extracting the tokens from there. Does that mean the manifest and everything is correct or does hardcoding circumvent the sso and therefore does not mean my code is correct?
